# Sender email address not included in EmailJS

Tags: javascript, html, api

When I submit the form, I receive the user's message. However, I don't know who it's from. I don't receive their email address, nor their name. I tried looking at their documentation but wasn't able to get past this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        // https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration
        emailjs.init("MY_USER_ID");
    })();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {document.getElementById("contact-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // generate a five digit number for the contact_number variable
        this.contact_number.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;
        // these IDs from the previous steps
        emailjs.sendForm("MY_SERVICE_ID", "MY_TEMPLATE_ID", this).then(
        function () {
        console.log("SUCCESS!");
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("FAILED...", error);
        }
        );
    });};
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="contact-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="contact_number" />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" />
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you post your template?

Comment: @Jejun yes, here it is:

You got a new email from {{from_name}}:

{{message}}


Let me know if you want more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`{{message}}` is the only thing you can receive from the form for now because your template has two dynamic variables `{{from_name}}`, **`{{message}}`** but you are sending `contact_number`, `user_name`, `user_email` and **`message`** which is written in name attributes for each inputs in the form.

You have to match names of template variables and names of form inputs. If you want to maintain your form, you have to modify your template like

from `You got a new email from {{from_name}}: {{message}}`

to `You got a new email from {{user_name}}({{user_email}}): {{message}}`

You can also use built-in variables without getting input but I'll leave them because you need to [read the documentation](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/dynamic-variables-templates/) for good.